Bioutil (Touch ID) is not working correctly in terminal of macOS Sonoma 14.5
I have a problem using bioutil command in terminal.
In macOS Sonoma 14.5, I submitted bioutil -r -s in terminal to review the system touch ID configuration.
But I got the following unknown error:
AssertMacros: devices.count > 0,  file: /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/91a344b1-f985-11ee-b563-fe8bc7981bff/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/BiometricKit/bioutil/bioutil.m, line: 79, value: 0
AssertMacros: err == 0 ,  file: /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/91a344b1-f985-11ee-b563-fe8bc7981bff/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/BiometricKit/bioutil/bioutil.m, line: 500, value: 61
Error occured, err = 0x3d.

Then I entered the same command in another macbook (macOS 15.0) then I got the correct response on that one like the following:
System Touch ID Configuration:
     Biometrics functionality: 1
     Biometrics for unlock: 1
     Biometric timeout (in seconds): 172800
     Match timeout (in seconds): 14400
     Passcode input timeout (in seconds): 861600
Operation performed successfully.

So bioutil worked correctly in macOS 15.0.
Does macOS Sonoma 14.5 have the bioutil technical error, or Did I entered the command wrong?
How could I fix the bioutil error in macOS 14.5?

It seems that the device.count variable in bioutil program is 0, so it throws an error. Is your touch id working properly? bioutil is does not seem to be open source unfortunately
